# Is it possible to pass intents without getting the bundle?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a custom receiver that I pass data to from my activity. Let's call this receiver IntentReceiver().

Once IntentReceiver() receives the intent, I fire off another intent which passes the data to a service that processes the data in the background. Let's call this service IntentService(). Is there a way to directly pass the data to IntentReceiver() without getting the data from the bundle and then repackaging it as a new intent? My current code is below:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String address = extras.getString("address");

    Intent readIntent = new Intent(context, IntentService.class);
    readIntent.putExtra("address", address);
    context.startService(readIntent);
}
```

This code uses the following behavior: Intent --> Bundle --> Intent

Is there a way to make it: Intent --> Intent

Comment: Try `Intent readIntent = new Intent(intent).setClass(context, MessageService.class);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than repacking in another bundle you can use the same intent object and further call set class as described by @CommonsWare like

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    intent.setClass(context, MessageService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```